# Overarching driver question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I'm seeing a *lot* of questions related to fixing missing drivers and I've asked many myself and they've never been answered. I assume, now, that this is because the solution is really same and sort of self-explanatory (look up the driver, install) and no one wants to bother answering questions that have the same solution so . . .

I propose that someone asks a general question regarding missing drivers, someone answers it, and we begin the process of marking all the others as duplicates of the general one and marking new ones as duplicates of it, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not be really *that* possible to create a new thread just for teaching how to install drivers. You know, different hardware uses different drivers, and they each have different setup methods. It is possible that it will create a mess instead of useful information.

Another thing is that some manufacturer does not provide any Ubuntu, or even Linux driver support, which may cause confusion to those who have those drivers but not able to find any useful soultion from the general answer.

Yes, many people have questions regarding missing drivers, but then, they each relate to different type of drivers needed. It is really not *that* possible to just open a general question for drivers and mark all others duplicate. It will either cause the general answer be serveral pages long or make it a mess.